# Get Own control values in visual basic 10

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for a way to get the data of control (in this case a Trackbar) inside the trackbar itself.

I got this:

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    Label1.Text = TrackBar1.Value
End Sub
```

But I want to replace that "trackBar1." with something like

```
    Label1.Text = THIS_CONTROL.Value
```

Is this possible in Vb10 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sender` argument:

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    Dim THIS_CONTROL As TrackBar = DirectCast(sender, TrackBar)
    Label1.Text = THIS_CONTROL.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This does the trick, I was looking for something that I remembered from other language that was like "this." but really I don't remember in what language that was, maybe visual FoxPro.

Comment: C++, C#, javascript, etc all have a `this` keyword, but in none of those languages would it do what you're looking for here. In every case, it would refer to the form, not the control, like `Me` in VB.